# Access db as localhost from docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm pretty new to Docker but am trying to use it to clean up some of my projects. One such project is a fairly simple PHP/MySQL application. I've "docker-ized" the app by adding a docker-compose.yml with db and php services. Here's my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'
services:
  php:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./public_html:/var/www/html
    links:
      - db
  db:
    image: mysql:5.5
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
        MYSQL_USER: root
        MYSQL_PASSWORD:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:
        MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
    volumes:
      - /c/dockerdata:/var/lib/mysql
```

This works correctly however I have to change all my PHP scripts to use "db" instead of "localhost" when connecting to the mysql database. I'm adding the docker stuff just as a way to clean up development so I'm trying to avoid changing the PHP code itself. Is there a way I can configure this so I'm able to use localhost or 127.0.0.1 to connect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker doesn't allow you to modify /etc/hosts on containers [Known issue](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/22224)

You can edit /etc/hosts with entrypoint option

Create entrypoint.sh script

```
#!/bin/bash
cp /etc/hosts /tmp/hosts
sed -e '/localhost/ s/^#*/#/' -i /tmp/hosts
cp /tmp/hosts /etc/hosts
# add your command here to run php application
```

Add execute permissions to entrypoint.sh

```
chmod +x entrypoint.sh
```

Add below two lines to Dockerfile

```
ADD entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT /entrypoint.sh
```

Now do the step 2) from my previous answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using below two steps

1) Add below CMD to your Dockerfile

`CMD sed -e '/localhost/ s/^#*/#/' -i /etc/hosts`

2) Replace 'db' with 'localhost' in docker-compose.yml

`links:
      - db
  db:
    image: mysql:5.5`

as

`links:
      - localhost
  localhost:
           image: mysql:5.5`

Comment: I get the following: 

php_1        | sed: cannot rename /etc/sed6KFTSI: Device or resource busy